# How do I retrieve a key object from a Map?

Tags: java, collections

Take two instances of the same class A, called foo and bar, where:

```
foo != bar
foo.equals(bar) == true
```

In other words, foo and bar are different instances but with the same hash code. Now take an instance of `Map<A,B>` called "map", where foo is a key in map. Is it possible to retrieve foo from Map, using bar? Currently I iterate through the key set and compare every key but **is there a faster way**? There don't seem to be any methods in Map for retrieving keys.

I am willing to try any data structure that implements Map or can work like a map.

Why do I want to do this? I'm trying to avoid retaining any more instances than necessary. Once I find foo I can release bar.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: If `foo.equals(bar)==true` what difference does it make which object reference you have? Just use `bar` since you have that.

Comment: If `foo.equals(bar)==true` how can you have both these  `foo` and `bar` as key in a `Map`?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I didn't say bar was in the Map.

Comment: If you have this problem you're misusing `Map.` You shouldn't care what instance of the key you have, you only care about its `hashCode()` and `equals()` properties.

Comment: @JasonCoco What I'm trying to do is avoid retaining any more instances than necessary. foo and bar may be equivalent but they use double the memory.

Comment: But why do you have two instances of the key?

Comment: I'm with @EJP can you tell a little more about the problem? Like how the key is generated/constructed where you'd be likely to get multiple copies? Can you not just construct the copy, look up the value and discard the copy?

Comment: @EJP & JasonCoco I create the second one to find the first one in the map, then I discard it. Or at least I want to. I'm not interested in the value (for now), I need to get the key value so I can return it to the caller.

Comment: You probably shouldn't worry about creating the extra key object. Creating small objects here and there is not a big deal for the garbage collector. As far as I know there's not a way to do what you're asking besides iterating the map (and doing so creates some more small objects).

Comment: If your keys have an order and you can use `TreeMap` instead, it has some methods for retrieving keys. But then you won't be using the hash code at all.

Comment: @Radiodef Yes I'm starting to think that is the way.

Comment: Really sad to see there isn't a more satisfactory answer to this.  Not sure why specific subclasses of Map, such as HashMap, couldn't provide a `getKey` method in addition to the standard implementation of Map.  It'd save a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache Commons Collections ™](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/). It has Bidirectional Maps `BidiMap`.
These represent maps where the key can lookup the value and the value can lookup the key with equal ease.

```
BidiMap bidi = new TreeBidiMap();
bidi.put("SIX", "6");
bidi.get("SIX");  // returns "6"
bidi.getKey("6");  // returns "SIX"
bidi.removeValue("6");  // removes the mapping
BidiMap inverse = bidi.inverseBidiMap();  // returns a map with keys and values swapped
```

#### See also

- [Commons Collections user guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/userguide.html)

Answer (score 1):

HashMap actually does have a method to retrieve the entry but it is package-private. I am not really sure why it isn't public to be honest. I don't think it exposes anything. You can, of course, call it with reflection.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(new String("hello"), "world!");

Method method = (
    HashMap.class.getDeclaredMethod("getEntry", Object.class)
);
method.setAccessible(true);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map.Entry<String, String> entry = (Map.Entry<String, String>)(
    method.invoke(map, new String("hello"))
);

System.out.println(entry.toString().replace("=", " ")); // hello world
```

The reflection probably makes it not useful in the scenario you've described but I guess it could be useful to others. I wouldn't recommend using it.

Answer (score 1):

Just using the existing map to find duplicztes doesn't seem to be enough. Use a second map, where you put(key,key) pairs. Then:

- map.get(key) == null if the key is not already there
- map.get(key) == firstObjectAllocated otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the source code of [HashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.get%28java.lang.Object%29)

If based on your implementation:
`foo.hashCode() == bar.hashCode()` and `foo.equals(bar)`

Then, yes you could directly get the value for key `foo` by
`map.get(bar)`

---

updated: sorry misunderstanding your question before
if you want to keep the key, why you don't just keep the key cached. Then to retrieve the key is hash tree mapping, should be fast.

```java
HashMap<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
HashMap<K,K> cacheKeys = new HashMap<K,K>();
cacheKeys.put(foo,foo);
map.put(foo,value);

//now you have var bar; you could retrieve the cached key
bar = cacheKeys.get(bar);//this will make bar = foo; the real bar will be gc
//then get the value 
val = map.get(bar);
```

Comment: No. That gives the *value* mapped to the key, not the key itself.

Comment: I think the question is strange, he didn't actually ask about retrieving the *value* for key `foo`, he asked about retrieving the actual object reference of the key from the map using an equivalent but different object reference.

Comment: @EJP that's what I said. He wants to retrieve `foo` using an equivalent but not equal object.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think to keep a cachekeys map could help you to improve the performance. And the cache do only keep the ref of the keys, it should not takes too much memory, since for sure, you will have the keys already in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This way may faster.

```
   Iterator<A> mapKeyIterator=map.keySet().iterator();
    while (mapKeyIterator.hasNext()){
        A key;
        if((key=mapKeyIterator.next()).equals(bar)) {
            return key;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now.